# Active Directory 'The specified domain already exist'

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

When I want to add an child domain under parent, I got the 'the specified domain already exist' error. 
I searched through google, and some one suggest that because I deleted one child domain(And I did) rather than demote it, there are some meta data left on parent domain server. So I followed the tutorial here to remove the meta and checked on the parent domain controller, it is clear. But still don't work.

https://www.petri.com/delete_failed_dcs_from_ad

So I cloned a virtual machine, cleaned it with sysprep command, and use a new child domain name. Still no luck.
Screen cast for error message
[image]

Answer (score 2):

After search, I find the solution. This error is reported due to the SID conflicts in parent AD DC. 
If you use a virtual machine as template and clone it to produce child AD DC, the children will have same SID.
To Solve this problem, you need to run sysprep and CHECK THE 'GENERALIZE' option. Otherwise, sysprep will not regenerate a new SID for you.